# access assets images from a vue instance within an array of objects

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a list of images. These images get stored into the `data` object of the vue instance. So within my HTML code I loop through this array and pass in the image path to the image source.

Unfortunately the images have a wrong asset path. An example code would be

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img v-for="item in items" :key="item.img" :src="item.img" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          img: "@/assets/logo.png"
        },
        {
          img: "./assets/logo.png"
        },
        {
          img: "../assets/logo.png"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

None of these paths seem to work. I also created a code example to show the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ryqrx5wym4

How can I access the images correctly?

Comment: have you tried `:src="require(item.img)"`

Comment: yes, this did not work

Comment: What build system are you using ? The answer differs if you are using Vite or Webpack

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the images into your public directory and then you will be able to access them with `img: "/assets/logo.png"`